# Which object has the highest time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

suppose there are wo objects A and B and A is travelling away from B velocity of V. but in B s perspective its A which is travelling that velocity of V. but we know answer to this question is the total energy of A . but lets imagine a scenario. A and B have the same rest mass. but B which we consider  has  a rest mass(relative to A), has internal particles that bouncing off the inside walls in very high speed. so A has a high velocity and B has internal energy than A. so the total energy of B relative to A is much higher.  so simply if  we were  to calculate time dilation for both, which one we should consider has the highest time dilation relative to the one another other. or may be compared to a third object as a clock ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear as it seems to be missing words, you should go through and make it more spear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ (say, two boxes) are moving relative to each other at constant velocity, the time dilation that $A$ perceives for $B$ is the same as the one that $B$ perceives for $A$ : the situation is symmetric. I don't think this has anything to do with what's inside $A$ or $B$.